# 30 positive integers, edited.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given any 30 positive integers, prove that we can find some integers so their sum is divisible by 30.
I don't know where to start. Please some hints.

Comment: It is an edited dublicate, it was me that wrote that problem, but for some reasons I couldnt login with that account

Comment: Impatient of me, sorry.

Comment: Its ok. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider congruences modulus 30...

Answer (score 1):

A number is divisible by $30$ if it equals $0$ mod $30$.  Can you take it from here?  (More answer below)

> Pick any $30$ numbers and add them together one by one, keeping a running total.  If at any point we get (a) $0$ mod $30$, or (b) the same value mod $30$ as we did earlier, we've won.  In case (a), we have the sum in hand.  In case (b), we subtract out the numbers before we reached that value the first time, and the sum of what's left will be divisible by $30$. Because we have $30$ integers, even if we never repeat, one of the sums *has* to be $0$ mod $30$ by the pigeonhole principle.